# Pull Data from TMX Using Python 3.6.8

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

About two months ago I asked a question about pulling data from the CME in the json format. I was successfully able to pull the appropriate data with your help.

Want to remind everyone that I am still pretty new to Python, so please bear with me if my question is relatively straightforward.

I am trying to pull data again again in json format but from a different website and things do not appear to be cooperating.  In particular I am trying to pull the following data:
`https://api.tmxmoney.com/marketactivity/candeal?ts=1567086212742`

This is what I have tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
cadGovt = 'https://api.tmxmoney.com/marketactivity/candeal?ts=1567086212742'
sample_data = requests.get(cadGovt)
sample_data.encoding = 'utf-8'
test = sample_data.json()
print(test)
```

I would like to get a json of the information (which is literally just a table that has term, description, bid yield, ask yield, change, bid price, ask price, change).

Instead I am getting 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'.

If anyone has any guidance or advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cause the page you're getting is not returning `JSON` but an HTML page. So when you try to use

`test = sample_data.json()`

You're trying to parse HTML as JSON which won't work. You can scrape the data off of the page though, here's an example in bs4 you can try, it's a bit rusty on the edges but it should work.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
url = 'https://api.tmxmoney.com/marketactivity/candeal?ts=1567086212742'
response = r.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print(tr.text+"\n")
```

you can get the TD such as this

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
```

Comment: Is there a way to covert it from HTML to JSON so that I can access the table?

Comment: None that I am aware of, if you really need the data you can scrape it off of the page using BeautifulSoup (https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). I'll write a short example if you'd like?

Comment: that would be amazing if you could!!

Comment: Sure, give me a few. A bit rusty on my bs4.

Comment: Hey @Unknown1984 I just edited my post, try to see if it works for you.

Comment: it worked perfectly thanks! Now I just want to put the info into a DataFrame.  Thanks for your help!!